# Download thru the browser a file locally stored

Tags: javascript, java

On the server side I create a new file (Java):

```
File file = new File(dataConverter.convertData(body.get("type").trim(), dataFile));
```

On the client side I want to download the file, so I try accessing the file using its absolute path (JavaScript):

```
document.open('C:\\Users\\dmuntean\\Desktop\\Minivsita\\earlyproject\\output\\downloads\\temp\\');
```

But because everything is stored on local disk, the browser (Chrome) doesn't let me do this, it redirects me on a blank page and nothing happens. Is there any workaround?

I tried using window.location, window.open, document.location. Also launching Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[document.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) actually open a document for writing (and can actually erase the file content, if already exist). To do what you want, you have to use somenthing like:

```
document.location.href = 'file:///c:/path/to/file/document.pdf';
```

*Tested on Firefox 68.0.1 and Chrome 75.0.3770.142*

Comment: Still doesn't work - same problem, it redirects me on about:blank#blocked

Comment: Sorry i miss the **blocked**: you have accidentally blocked your URL, just go to **chrome://settings/content/popups** in your chrome browser and remove the url.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed

Comment: try with another browser, just to be sure